# R rmarkdown external image thumbnail in html table

Tags: r, r-markdown

I created an html table with the display of images from a monitor
the images are almost 800
now the images are displayed with an html

in this form: `<a href="https://kc.kobotoolbox.org/attachment/original?media_file=bonushenricus/attachments/1631348129389.jpg"><img src="/home/bonushenricus/R/kobotoolbox/foto_kobotoolbox_ovature/thumb_1631348129389.jpg"alt="NA" height=80></a>`

and opened with DT packages

[this is a link to an example of the results (only first rows)](https://rpubs.com/bonushenricus/810231/)

this means that the page that opens has about 1 Gb that is downloaded
do you have any advice for me on how to put thumbnails in the table?

I tried with the rmdformats package, heading rmarkdown like this
output:

```
output:      
    rmdformats::html_docco:
        thumbnails: true
```

but it didn't work with DT, rpubs doesn't take it

so I'm trying with imager
For now I have taken this function from a questions in stackoverflow

```
makeThumb <- function(file) {
    library(imager)
    im <- load.image(paste0("https://kc.kobotoolbox.org/attachment/original?media_file=bonushenricus/attachments/",file))
    img <- resize(im,round(width(im)/10),round(height(im)/10))
    save.image(img,paste0("thumb_",file))
}
```

but I need to load all the images directly into the table, then create a cimg class for each image, and I'm afraid it will load me too much memory
or I have to find a way to upload the thumbnails to a server and reconstruct the html for each photo

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide some code sample or data sample to be able to understand better your issue?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you ask an incomplete question and someone sees it, correct it by editing it. **Do not answer with a question in response or create confusion.** Second, why do you include libraries in your function with the `require` command? Instead, write `library(jpeg)` and `library(imager)` at the beginning of the script.
I suggest that you delete your answer and correct the question.

Comment: excuse me
I hope it has improved a little
Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

OKAY. I will show you step by step how to do it correctly. Unfortunately, I cannot access the kc.kobotoolbox.org website. So I did this for the files stored in the local folder. I suggest you do the same.

So let's get started.

1. Run RStudio and create a new project.
2. In the project directory, create an img directory and collect there all the files you want to convert.
3. Create a new R script
4. First, load the libraries you need

```
library(fs)
library(imager)
```

5. Now we will read the names of all the `jpg` files from the `img` directory over and over, turning them into a list.

```
files = dir_ls("img", regexp = "\\.jpg$") %>% as.list()
```

For me, the `files` list has this content

```
$`img/img1 (1).jpg`
[1] "img/img1 (1).jpg"

$`img/img1 (2).jpg`
[1] "img/img1 (2).jpg"

$`img/img1 (3).jpg`
[1] "img/img1 (3).jpg"

$`img/img1 (4).jpg`
[1] "img/img1 (4).jpg"

$`img/img1 (5).jpg`
[1] "img/img1 (5).jpg"
```

6. Now the hardest thing. We need to create a function that converts our files. Let's call it `ResizeImg`.

```
ResizeImg = function(file, xscale = .1, yscale = .1){ 
  if(file_exists(file)){
    thumb_file = paste0(path_dir(file), "/", "thumb_", path_file(file))
    if(file_exists(thumb_file)) file_delete(thumb_file)
    im = file %>% load.image() 
    im %>% resize(round(width(im)*xscale),round(height(im)*yscale)) %>% 
      save.image(thumb_file)
  }
}
```

Let's see if it works

```
files[[1]] %>% ResizeImg(.25, .25)
```

Everything is great, so let's use our new function

```
files %>% lapply(ResizeImg, xscale = .15, yscale = .15)
```

Everything works perfectly as expected.